# Get next li id element in ul with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">element 1</li>
  <li id="2">element 2</li>
  <li><div>random text</div></li>
  <li id="3">element 3</li>
</ul>
```

When I click a `li` element I get the next `li` id, I've been using `next()`, but it only works with the first one, after the `div` with the random text I can't get the third id, it just says '`undefined`' the `div` can't go in other place.

Comment: This is an invalid html. UL cannot have a div as its direct child

Comment: So can i put the div between li tags?

Comment: Yeah. That will be valid.

Comment: Numeric IDs are invalid before HTML5 too, and older browsers will balk at them. They're generally a bad idea anyway because it's far too easy to have duplicate IDs...

Comment: Thanks, so, done that, how can I get the 3rd li id by clicking the second one?

Comment: If you post you script too, we might be able to help figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the 3:rd `li` doesn't have an `id` you will get an undefined in return.

This means that the function you use need to recursively move to the next until it iterated all the children.